# How to change the color of JQgrid

Tags: jqgrid, colors

I have a jqGrid and it has a default color: blue. However I want to change it's color. What can I do?

**EDIT:** I have that includes for jqgrid CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ui.multiselect.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present you are using custom classes jQueryUI. The file in question is 
*jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css*.

I will recommend or use a template already defined that your choice here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ in the Gallery section.

Once you've chosen a theme, for example, "Cupertino" change this line of code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css"/>
```

with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
```

however, if you want a custom version from a theme already defined; click on edit and you are shown a screen where you yourself can change the colors of all elements of jQueryUI and once finished editing, you download the custom theme and I include it in your project.
I hope I was clear!

Comment: I remove that line: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>` and put yours but my page's design and functionalit goes crazy?

Comment: you don't remove line jqgrid css, but add css jqueryui! jqgrid use ccs   jqueryui!

Comment: I have edited my question. Also how about the button and arrow colors?