# Customize jQGrid colors using MVC 4 ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, jqgrid

I´m using jQGrid as my main data entry mechanism for an internet project.

I entered into [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and did my custom theme, as I want Windows 8 look&feel. Everything fine, and I downloaded my theme.

Now I have problems attaching it to my jQGrid. I tried to change the following code:

```
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jqgrid").Include(
                    "~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/jquery.ui.all.css"));
```

To my new theme:

```
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jqgrid").Include(
                    "~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/MyTheme/jquery.ui-1.10.13.custom.css"));
```

And I can see that no theme is being used (the lines, shadows and everything disappeared on screen).

I realized that I got several files downloaded from ThemeRoller, but I followed these steps [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/how-to-change-theme-of-grid/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529762/how-to-change-the-color-of-jqgrid) with no success.

This really can´t work as the original `jquery.ui.all.css` calls another files that does all the work. If I change this call, of course these itens will not be called.

The problems is that the files downloaded has incompatible match with the files I have in Content/themes, so there I don´t know how to match thigs.

I need help on that please. Also, if there is a better way to change jqGrid colors on the fly I would accept the hint, as it sounds much easier.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with jqGrid and MVC: [jqGrid Results over flow the grid and "Please, Select Row" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876950/jqgrid-results-over-flow-the-grid-and-please-select-row-message)

I ended up creating a plain HTML page to get everything to work correctly.

Before doing that though, you might verify that the correct files are being loaded.  You can use IE or Chrome Dev Tools to verify the css files have loaded.

Comment: My point is: What are the correct files that needs to be loaded ? ThemeRoller returned me with a different file structure that I have installed on jQuery. So, which ones should be avoided and wich ones should be added?

Comment: Not sure if you were able to figure this out since you accepted my answer, but I would guess the same two files aren't getting loaded. (ui.jqgrid.css and the jquery-ui*.css)